# Stormcrawler not fetching/indexing pages for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I am using the Stormcrawler with the Elasticsearch [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTerugU12TY)  and no pages are shown with the `FETCHED` status in Kibana while crawling the webpage http://books.toscrape.com/

Still on the console the webpages appear to be fetched and parsed

```
48239 [Thread-26-fetcher-executor[3 3]] INFO  c.d.s.b.FetcherBolt - [Fetcher #3] Threads : 0    queues : 1      in_queues : 1
48341 [FetcherThread #7] INFO  c.d.s.b.FetcherBolt - [Fetcher #3] Fetched http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/index.html with status 200 in msec 86
48346 [Thread-46-parse-executor[5 5]] INFO  c.d.s.b.JSoupParserBolt - Parsing : starting http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/index.html
48362 [Thread-46-parse-executor[5 5]] INFO  c.d.s.b.JSoupParserBolt - Parsed http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/index.html in 13 msec
```

Also it seems that the index of Elasticsearch gets some items even though these have no title

[Screenshot of Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEPOp.png)

I expanded the `com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.IndexerBolt` to also store the metadata of a web page in a local file and it seems like it does not get any tuples at all. Since the IndexerBolt also marks the status of a url as `FETCHED` that would explain the mentioned observation in Kibana.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour? I already reverted the crawler configuration to the standard, except the index bolt in crawler.flux to run my class.

The Topology Configuration:

```
name: "crawler"

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false



    - resource: false
      file: "es-conf.yaml"
      override: true

spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout"
    parallelism: 10

bolts:
  - id: "partitioner"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "fetcher"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "sitemap"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parse"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "index"
    className: "de.hpi.bpStormcrawler.IndexerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status_metrics"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.StatusMetricsBolt"
    parallelism: 1

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "partitioner"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - from: "spout"
    to: "status_metrics"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - from: "partitioner"
    to: "fetcher"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "sitemap"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "parse"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "parse"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "parse"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "index"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"
```

The reconfigured IndexerBolt

```java
package de.hpi.bpStormcrawler;

/**
 * Licensed to DigitalPebble Ltd under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * DigitalPebble licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


import static com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.Constants.StatusStreamName;
import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.jsonBuilder;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.storm.metric.api.MultiCountMetric;
import org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;
import org.elasticsearch.action.DocWriteRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.Metadata;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.indexing.AbstractIndexerBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.persistence.Status;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.ConfUtils;

/**
 * Sends documents to ElasticSearch. Indexes all the fields from the tuples or a
 * Map &lt;String,Object&gt; from a named field.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class IndexerBolt extends AbstractIndexerBolt {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(IndexerBolt.class);

    private static final String ESBoltType = "indexer";

    static final String ESIndexNameParamName = "es.indexer.index.name";
    static final String ESDocTypeParamName = "es.indexer.doc.type";
    private static final String ESCreateParamName = "es.indexer.create";

    private OutputCollector _collector;

    private String indexName;
    private String docType;

    // whether the document will be created only if it does not exist or
    // overwritten
    private boolean create = false;
    File indexFile;

    private MultiCountMetric eventCounter;

    private ElasticSearchConnection connection;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
                        OutputCollector collector) {
        super.prepare(conf, context, collector);
        _collector = collector;

        indexName = ConfUtils.getString(conf, IndexerBolt.ESIndexNameParamName,
                "fetcher");
        docType = ConfUtils.getString(conf, IndexerBolt.ESDocTypeParamName,
                "doc");
        create = ConfUtils.getBoolean(conf, IndexerBolt.ESCreateParamName,
                false);

        try {
            connection = ElasticSearchConnection
                    .getConnection(conf, ESBoltType);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            LOG.error("Can't connect to ElasticSearch", e1);
            throw new RuntimeException(e1);
        }

        this.eventCounter = context.registerMetric("ElasticSearchIndexer",
                new MultiCountMetric(), 10);

        indexFile = new File("/Users/jonaspohlmann/code/HPI/BP/stormCrawlerSpike/spikeStormCrawler2/index.log");
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {

        String url = tuple.getStringByField("url");

        // Distinguish the value used for indexing
        // from the one used for the status
        String normalisedurl = valueForURL(tuple);

        Metadata metadata = (Metadata) tuple.getValueByField("metadata");
        String text = tuple.getStringByField("text");


        //BP: added Content Field
        String content = new String(tuple.getBinaryByField("content"));

        boolean keep = filterDocument(metadata);
        if (!keep) {
            eventCounter.scope("Filtered").incrBy(1);
            // treat it as successfully processed even if
            // we do not index it
            _collector.emit(StatusStreamName, tuple, new Values(url, metadata,
                    Status.FETCHED));
            _collector.ack(tuple);
            return;
        }

        try {
            XContentBuilder builder = jsonBuilder().startObject();

            // display text of the document?
            if (fieldNameForText() != null) {
                builder.field(fieldNameForText(), trimText(text));
            }

            // send URL as field?
            if (fieldNameForURL() != null) {
                builder.field(fieldNameForURL(), normalisedurl);
            }


            // which metadata to display?
            Map<String, String[]> keyVals = filterMetadata(metadata);

            Iterator<String> iterator = keyVals.keySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String fieldName = iterator.next();
                String[] values = keyVals.get(fieldName);
                if (values.length == 1) {
                    builder.field(fieldName, values[0]);
                    try {
                        saveStringToFile(indexFile, fieldName + "\t" + values[0]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (values.length > 1) {
                    builder.array(fieldName, values);
                }
            }

            builder.endObject();

            String sha256hex = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
                    .sha256Hex(normalisedurl);

            IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, docType,
                    sha256hex).source(builder);

            DocWriteRequest.OpType optype = DocWriteRequest.OpType.INDEX;

            if (create) {
                optype = DocWriteRequest.OpType.CREATE;
            }

            indexRequest.opType(optype);

            connection.getProcessor().add(indexRequest);

            eventCounter.scope("Indexed").incrBy(1);

            _collector.emit(StatusStreamName, tuple, new Values(url, metadata,
                    Status.FETCHED));
            _collector.ack(tuple);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Error sending log tuple to ES", e);
            // do not send to status stream so that it gets replayed
            _collector.fail(tuple);
        }
    }
    private void saveStringToFile(File file, String stringToWrite) throws IOException {
        String pathName = file.getPath();
        File folder = file.getParentFile();

        if (!folder.exists() && !folder.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Couldn't create the storage folder: " + folder.getAbsolutePath() + " does it already exist ?");
        }

        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true))) {
            out.append(stringToWrite + '\n');

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you merged all your configs i.e generic SC + specific ES one into a single *es-conf.yaml*? If not then your Flux file is probably missing

```
   - resource: false
     file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
     override: true
```

where the indexer config typically looks like:

```
  indexer.url.fieldname: "url"
  indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
  indexer.canonical.name: "canonical"
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.keywords=keywords
  - parse.description=description
  - domain=domain
```

Not having any md mappings defined would explain why your modified indexer does not write to the files and why the index contains urls but no additional fields.

Please note that the 'index' index (excuse the terminology) does not contain the status of the URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316316/432844 for an explanation of status vs index.

Comment: Perfekt now it appears in the file but not in the 'index' of elastic search and also the `FETCHED` status is not set.

What also does `ressource: false` mean when it is still required?

Comment: Did you refresh the index definition in Kibana? If not it will only show the fields defined when you created the index. FETCHED: are you talking about the status index? 
From http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/flux.html => If the resource property is set to true, the include will be loaded as a classpath resource from the value of the file attribute, otherwise it will be treated as a regular file.

Comment: Ok now the title is also in kibana under the index :)

Yes I am talking about the status index which is only DISCOVERED for everything.

Ah ok thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried filtering on the status value in Kibana? You are probably seeing the first 500 docs only. Maybe try 'curl "localhost:9200/status/_count?pretty&q=status:FETCHED"' to get the counts

Comment: Have you tried filtering on the status value in Kibana? You are probably seeing the first 500 docs only. Maybe try 'curl "localhost:9200/status/_count?pretty&q=status:FETCHED"' to get the counts

Comment: Yes we did but filtering in Kibana but did not work. We filtered for status codes FETCHED which didn't return anything and filtering for status codes not DISCOVERED which also didn't return a result. Still according to the query to elasticsearch you posted there are many pages with the code FETCHED.. Maybe it is a misconfiguration of Kibana? I also already tried to refresh the index definitions.

Comment: not sure what the issue is, could be Kibana indeed but as long as the curl returned counts for FETCHED then there is no issue with the index itself. Please feel free to mark the answer above as useful and / or accepted.

Comment: Perfect! Do you have an idea where to further research the issue with Kibana?